# Reading a .txt file and getting stuck on first char

Tags: java, equals, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that looks something like this:

> p : 10001 : Unity
>
> c : 20007 : Witch   : Morgana: 10001 : 10 : 15 : 0
>
> t : 30001 : Gold    : 20004  : 50   : 2000
>
> a : 40002 : Wand    : 20006

I want to use ":" as a delimiter and do things with each line according to what the first char is.

```
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile()).useDelimiter(":");                                                 
    int index;
    String type;
    String name;

    String identifier = scanner.next(); 

    if (identifier == "p") {
        index = scanner.nextInt();
        name = scanner.next();
        partyList.add(new Party(index, name));

    } else if (identifier == "c") {
        index = scanner.nextInt();
        type = scanner.next();
        name = scanner.next();
        int partyC = scanner.nextInt();
        int empathyC = scanner.nextInt();
        double carryingCapacityC = scanner.nextDouble();
        creatureList.add(new Creature(index, type, name, partyC, empathyC,carryingCapacityC));

    } else if (identifier == "t") {
        index = scanner.nextInt();
        type = scanner.next();
        int creatureT = scanner.nextInt();
        double weightT = scanner.nextDouble();
        int valueT = scanner.nextInt();
        treasureList.add(new Treasure(index, type, creatureT, weightT, valueT));

    } else if (identifier == "a") {
        index = scanner.nextInt();
        type = scanner.next();
        int creatureA = scanner.nextInt();
        artifactList.add(new Artifact(index, type, creatureA));

    } else {
        System.out.println("This is not a valid line of input");
    }
    System.out.println("Identifier: " + identifier);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This shouldn't be too difficult... However, when I run the program I get something like this:

```
You chose to open this file: testFileSC.txt 

This is not a valid line of input 

Identifier: p 

This is not a valid line of input 

Identifier: 10002

//etc. (you get the point) all the way through my text file.
```

So it's reading the file okay, but getting stuck on the first char. Furthermore making everything an 'identifier'. Any ideas? I've been staring at this for way too long!

Answer (score 3):

Identifier is a String.  You cannot use == to check the value of a string.  == will check to see if the two objects are the same, which they are not.  One object is a string variable; the other object is a constant.  Using the `.equals()` method will check the value of the String.

```
if( identifier.equals("p"))
 ...
```

If you want to cover the circumstance in which whitespaces may be included, you can also do:

```
if( identifier.startsWith("p"))
```

Comment: This is correct. `==` operator is comparing memory adresses which is always false. Instead you should use the `equals` which compares the value of the Strings

Comment: One last thing: I changed my code as you suggested and this gets rid of the issue completely. However, now it's stopping on the first line. (i.e when it prints it's only printing one 'p'- not the rest of the letters). Any idea?

Comment: @tommy1370, you need to put your code in a loop until it finishes reading the entire file.

Comment: @AdelBoutros Well there is one special case... **just as curiosity** `String s1="String"; String s2="String"; s1==s2?`

Comment: @wmz Nope `s1 != s2` because when you do `s1 = "String"`, in java it is actually interpreted as `s1 = new String("String")`. So **s1** and **s2** references 2 **different** (new) objects. They will never be equal unless you say `String s1 = "String"; s2 = s1;`

Answer (score 2):

You should not compare strings using ==, but instead use .equals() such as

```
"wantedvalue".equals(variable)
```

or

```
variable1.equals(variable2)
```

The equals methods test if the are equal in the sense that they look the same while == checks if they are the actual same object. Compare with taking two equal pen. They look the same (equals) but they are not the same pen (==).

Answer (score 2):

Use `"p".equals(identifier)` instead of `identifier == "p"`.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you need to use `.equals()` instead of `==` to check the strings. Another thing is that you're using `":"` as a delimiter which means that the tokens will include spaces. For example, the first identifier would be `"p "` instead of `"p"`. You can use the `.trim()` method to remove any trailing spaces and then use `.equals()` for comparison like this:

```
if (identifier.trim().equals("p")) {
```

You also need to put your code in a loop to read the entire file. You could enclose it in a while loop until your `scanner` throws a `NoSuchElementException` which will indicate that you've read the entire file.

Reference [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).

Comment: Thanks! Could I just do this? `.useDelimiter("//s*://s*");`

Comment: Actually, it is more efficient to put the trim at the beginning, or you will be calling it every time.  ie: String identifier = scanner.next().trim();  Although I don't expect it makes a difference for your homework project.

Comment: @EricB.: He's also retrieving tokens inside the `if` conditional blocks so would have to change the code there as well. Just wondering, though... how would doing it this way make it more efficient?

Comment: @Dawood: Doing it a single time invokes the function once and stores it in the identifier variable.  Otherwise, it must invoke the function every time it tries the comparison.  Consequently, if it makes it to the bottom of the if/else statement, it will have invoked the trim() command 4 times instead of once.  Not to mention, it just adds a lot of extra verbiage to the code for no real additional value.

Comment: @EricB.: I understand, you're right. That would be useful if no further tokens were being retrieved inside the `if` conditional blocks but since he's retrieving numerous tokens inside those blocks, it would probably make more sense to use a delimiter with whitespace on both sides (as OP suggested), otherwise they would also have to be sanitized separately. I realized after posting that my solution is not so efficient... thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use == to compare Strings in Java (not in the way you intended).